# % and * together on the dependency line

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have been using strange rules like this for a long time, but suddenly they are breaking on a new environment.

Is there a robust way to do this?

```
all: test.1.out

test.%.out: %/test*.out
    /bin/cp -f $< $@
```

On my box (ubuntu):

```
alishan:~/Dropbox/make_insanity> make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
alishan:~/Dropbox/make_insanity> make
/bin/cp -f 1/test.out test.1.out
```

No problem with this kind of code on other people's Macs, ubuntu machines, ubuntu virtual machines. Don't know all their make versions, but it seems like OK code.

On my mageia server in the same directory after clearing.

```
[dushoff@yushan make_insanity]$ make --version
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-mageia-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
[dushoff@yushan make_insanity]$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `test.1.out', needed by `all'.  Stop.
[dushoff@yushan make_insanity]$
```

Changing *either* the `%` or `*` to appropriate text "fixes" the problem, but of course does not produce the desired generality.

Comment: It has been suggested to me that the change from make 3.81 to 3.82 is the likely culprit. I looked at the release notes but didn't find anything that seemed to apply. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/make-alpha/2010-07/msg00025.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely sure but I think you want

```
test.<name>.out
```

to be made from

```
<name>/test.out
```

(if it exists). If that's right, you can do it robustly by reverse-engineering
the name of the prerequisite for each target from the name of the target, e.g.

```
targs := test.1.out test.a.out

define src_of =
$(patsubst .%,%,$(suffix $(basename $(1))))/$(basename $(basename $(1)))$(suffix $(1))
endef

all: $(targs)

test.%.out: $(call src_of,test.%.out)
    cp -f $< $@

clean:
    rm -f *.*.out
```

It's a bit of a mouthful, admittedly.

So if we pre-arrange a demo where the prerequisites exist:

```
$ ls -LR
.:
1  a  Makefile

./1:
test.out

./a:
test.out
$ make
cp -f 1/test.out test.1.out
cp -f a/test.out test.a.out
```

Comment: Thanks. That's useful in terms of learning cool stuff about make, but I could accomplish that using the original rule without the *. Also, in this particular application, it's important that the rules be readable.

This simple rule was working for a while on a variety of platforms. It would be nice if I could save it with something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) and the wildcard function. Note it was never valid without this, so whatever code you saw this is should be considered broken.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

all: test.1.out

test.%.out: $$(wildcard $$*/test*.out)
    @echo Prerequisites found: $^
```

Note the use of `$*` rather than `%` for the pattern match (see [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables)) is escaped by an extra `$`, and the whole thing is set to expand twice so both sets of values get expanded.

That being said this whole layout looks wrong. You were using `$<` which only matches the first word of the prerequisites even though with a wildcard there you may have a lot of them. [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33673212/313192) is probably a better bet as far as re-organizing your Makefile to actually be robust.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted.

I do understand what both of you are saying about structure.

This particular use-case involved people supplying files with slightly inconsistent names in real time, so I was stuck with bad structure (of course I could have tried to fix that upstream of make, but I typically think make first for everything). I should have said that in the first place.